# Reading samples, from a file, into an array

Tags: arrays, haskell, bytestring, repa

I've written a program that analyzes sample data that is contained an a file. Currently, my program reads the samples into a list and I perform the further analyzation/processing on the list of samples (`[Float]`).

I'm not quite happy with the performance and I'm thinking about using Arrays instead of lists for better performance. I'm also looking into parallelizing my implementation and `Data.Array.Repa` looks promising.

Currently, reading from the file goes something like this:

1. I read all the samples into a `ByteString`, using `hGet`.
2. I know each sample is represented by 3 bytes, so I group the `ByteString` into a list of `ByteString`s of 3.
3. I map my `toFloat` function on the list of `ByteString`s to get a list of `Float`s.

This results in the `[Float]` that I analyze to get the desired information.

I'm wondering at which step in this process I should start using an Array. I first thought about using the `listArray` function to transform my `[Float]` into an array of floats. I'm not sure, but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way.

Would it be possible to use `Data.Array.Repa.fromFunction` to construct the array right after step 2 and skip the intermediate `[Float]`? For the function, could I use something like `(map toFloat bsList)`? Where `bsList` is the list of `ByteString`s after grouping.

Or is there a way to read the samples directly into an array?

Comment: If your program is small, it might be nice to post (or link) it too. It'll make our answer much more concrete (and verifiable).

Comment: @Alec I'm sorry, but I'm not allowed to share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repa is actually capable of operating on ByteString as a backend for an array. So you can start processing ByteString in parallel right of the bet by  trying something along those lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack runghc --package repa

import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Array.Repa as R
import Data.Array.Repa.Repr.ByteString as R

getFloatsArr :: ByteString -> Array D DIM1 Float
getFloatsArr bs = R.traverse strArr (\(Z :. n) -> Z :. (n `div` 3)) getFloat where
  strArr = R.fromByteString (Z :. BS.length bs) bs
  getFloat getWord8 (Z :. k) =
    toFloat (getWord8 (Z :. k*3)) (getWord8 (Z :. k*3+1)) (getWord8 (Z :. k*3+2))
  toFloat = undefined -- convert to `Float` from 3 `Word8`s

processFurther :: Array U DIM1 Float -> a
processFurther = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = do
  bs <- BS.readFile "file.txt"
  arr <- R.computeUnboxedP $ getFloatsArr bs
  processFurther arr
  return ()
```